# How would you solve this problem using a hash map instead of a set?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, hashmap, set

```
def pair_sum(array,r_sum):
  if len(array)<2:
    return
  found = set()
  output= set()
  for num in array:
    k = r_sum - num
    if k not in found:
      found.add(num)
    else:
      output.add(((min(num,k)),(max((num,k)))))
  print('\n'.join(map(str,list(output))))
```

So for this question, if I have an array for example [4,1,2,5,3] and a target sum of 6 the function will return the two pairs of numbers which add up to the target sum so in this case, it would return (1,5) and (2,4). How would I do something similar using a hash map instead of a set?

Comment: Have you tried declaring `found` as a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desire to use a `hash map` instead of a `set` obviously comes from wanting to reduce the run time from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the `array`.

Here is an `O(n)` implementation using the python dictionary (hash map).

```
array = [4, 1, 2, 5, 3]
r_sum = 6

found = {}
while array:
    num = array.pop(0)
    k = r_sum - num
    if k in found:
        found[k] = True
    else:
        found[num] = False

for key, val in found.items():
    if val:
        print("({}, {})".format(key, r_sum - key))
```